# scheduledTimer with two decimal

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is it possible to use schedulerTimer with two decimals like

let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: **0.10**, target: self, selector: #selector(fireTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

the timeInterval is 0.10

Comment: Yes, you can. `TimeInterval` is just a typealias for `Double`. You can use how many decimal places that you like (of course at some point it will become pretty imprecise, but with two decimal paces you will be fine).

Comment: Ok nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely.

Just take noted that the `timeInterval` parameter in that `scheduedTimer` method is described as:

> The number of seconds between firings of the timer. **If `ti` is less
>   than or equal to 0.0, this method chooses the nonnegative value of 0.1
>   milliseconds instead.**

doc:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it by using `TimeInterval` and replace your desired value by 0.5

```
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(0.5), target: self, selector: #selector(//yourMethod), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

So the `scheduledTimer` in Foundation is

```
open class func scheduledTimer(timeInterval ti: TimeInterval, target aTarget: Any, selector aSelector: Selector, userInfo: Any?, repeats yesOrNo: Bool) -> Timer
```

where the `TimeInterval` is

```
public typealias TimeInterval = Double
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? Your proposed value of 0.5 still has only one decimal ;)

Comment: I didn't know that timeInterval is a type alias from double